# Grouped view for datasets in sonata admin list view

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, adminlte

I am wondering if there is a easy way to implement a group view for datasets grouped by its "root" element. 
Lets say i have a "person" entity. Many persons can have a "root" person they belong to. So i would add a reference to the person entity itself.

Now i don't want to show every person in the flat list view. Instead i want to display only every root-person and with clicking this dataset a accordion opens with the subordinated person entities ... how is that possible?

It would also be fine without a accordion, it can be enough if the subordinated entities are indented a bit ...

Can somebody give me a clue which approach i should follow? I would be the if i can reuse the most of the sonata admin functionality, especially the templates ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Was solving something similar in past. Got that working in few steps:

**Override first field in your Datagrid**

With this code you say that you want use my_custom_template.html.twig to render this field (in your admin class).

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $list)
{
    $list->add('yourFirstField', null, ['template' => 'my_custom_template.html.twig'])
}
```

**Enable filtering for yourFirstField**

Prepare filtering for your parent field (in your admin class)

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $filter)
{
    $filter->add('parent');
}
```

**Write custom template for first field**

Then in your custom template you use to set up filter value on click on link.

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %} 
{% block field %}
    {% if object.isRoot %}
        <a href="{{ path('your_route_list", {'filter[name][parent]': object.id} }}">{{ object.name }}</a>
    {% else %}
        {{ object.name }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

---

Later on you can override break breadcrumbs builder service (https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/breadcrumbs.html) and create nice path in breadcrumbs, so user can go navigate.